# How to show on login screen the last login informations (Windows 10)?

Tags: windows-10, login-screen

At least on Windows 7 professional in the Group Policy, there was a setting to get informations about time, user and successful or unsuccsessful logins, while on the login screen.

It seems not available in the Group Policy of Windows 10.

How to set it ?

Comment: More information on what method you used with Windows 7 would help isn’t how to find the same information on Windows 10.  Edit your question and add this vital information to your question

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once.

Comment: That's right, finally I found an answer after looking around for the Registry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the Registry and search a key:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System
>
> Create a new Value DWORD **DisplayLastLogonInfo** , if not already in the key.
>
> Set it to **1**

From [here](https://winaero.com/blog/show-the-last-logon-information-at-every-logon-in-windows-10/)